# How do I change the color of the pane dividing lines in tmux?

Tags: tmux, colors

I've used the following command to change the color of the status bar at the bottom of the screen:

```
set -g status-bg colour244
```

But I don't know how to change the color of the lines that divide the panes; currently, they're a mix of the original green and gray (color244). `man tmux` gives me a lot of info about the *status line* but this seems to refer to the status bar itself, not the dividing lines.

I suspect I'm just missing some terminology here.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You want `pane-active-border-style` and `pane-border-style`:

See the entry in the `man` page:

> pane-active-border-style style
>                      Set the pane border style for the currently active pane.  For how to specify style, see the message-command-style
>                      option.  Attributes are ignored.
>
>
>              pane-border-style style
>                      Set the pane border style for pane as aside from the active pane.  For how to specify style, see the
>                      message-command-style option.  Attributes are ignored.

So, in your `~/.tmux.conf` you could specify colours like so:

```
# border colours
set -g pane-border-style fg=magenta
set -g pane-active-border-style "bg=default fg=magenta"
```

Note, I use tmux 1.9a, and I find I get more consistent behaviour using:

```
set -g pane-border-fg magenta
set -g pane-active-border-fg green
set -g pane-active-border-bg default
```

Comment: I am getting a `unknown option: pane-border-style`, why is that? Edit: Ok I see that I have tmux `1.6`. And I think according to https://github.com/edkolev/tmuxline.vim/issues/23 it only works from 1.9+

Comment: Setting `pane-active-border-style` twice as in the first example will not work correctly. You have to specify both fg and bg in a single value (ie. separated with a space inside double quotes or comma and no quotes): `set -g pane-active-border-style bg=default,fg=magenta`

Answer (score 18):

As of tmux version `2.9` @jasonwryan 's implementation is reduced to two lines:

```
set -g pane-active-border-style bg=default,fg=magenta
set -g pane-border-style fg=green
```

Note lack of spacing between `bg` and `fg` declarations

[Source](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/1689#issuecomment-486722349)

Comment: Alternatively, use double quotes to specify multiple: 

`set -g pane-active-border-style "bg=default fg=magenta"`

Answer (score 1):

As of 3.0a, from the man page under set-option:
"With -a, and if the option expects a string or a style, value is appended to the existing setting.  For example:"

```
set -g pane-active-border fg=green
set -ag pane-active-border bg=magenta
```

This option is probably very olde, but I didn't see it here so I added it for completeness.
I used bg=***magenta*** so I could see it change when I tested it, not because of any bogus behavior when using -a with bg=***default***.  I did get a visit from the fashion police.