# How to change background color of a pane in tmux?

Tags: terminal, tmux, colors

I would like to change the background color of the inactive panes in tmux to better distinguish between the active pane and inactive panes. Something just a few shades different than the default. How could I do this?

Comment: Can you use [escape sequences for terminal colours](http://askubuntu.com/a/558422/251439)?

Comment: newly read through manpage of tmux 1.9 , seems only status lines and borders are customisable .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**UPDATE**:
A newer version of `tmux` now allows this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33553372/1204312

---

<strike>There is currently no way to do this.</strike>

See [this accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25533057/3650107) on stackoverflow which suggests changing pane-borders instead.

You can set values for `pane-active-border-style` and `pane-border-style` in your `~/.tmux.conf`.

[See this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/141252/109083) for more details configuring these values (and some inconsistencies between tmux versions).